# regex replace all leading spaces with something

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace all of the leading spaces in a string with something

[Here's what I tried so far](http://jsfiddle.net/FT4rP/)

```
var str = '     testing    1   2   3    ',
    regex = /^\s*/,
    newStr = str.replace(regex, '.');

document.write(newStr)
```

I want to get a result like:

```
'.....testing    1   2   3    '
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
var s = "   a b c";
print(s.replace(/^\s+/, function(m){ return m.replace(/\s/g, '.');}));
```

which prints:

```
...a b c
```

Comment: A shorter version of the exact same solution `STRING.replace(/^\s+/, (s) => (s.replace(/\s/g, '.')) )`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (ignores strnigs w/ no non-space)

```
var newStr = "";
newStr = (newStr = Array(str.search(/[^\s]/) + 1).join(".")) + str.substr(newStr.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
/^([ ]+)/
```

I'm not sure `\s` does the trick, while a plain  should be able to handle this!

Comment: This only provides 

    '.testing    1    2   3   '.
 One period.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, I need to use look-ahead for this, one moment =)

Comment: Nevermind, you should use @Bart's solution, it works really great!

Answer (score 0):

This is even shorter.

```
var text = "   a b c";
var result = s.replace(/\s/gy, ".");

console.log(result); // prints: "...a b c";
```

Why it works was explained for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982135/regex-to-replace-all-leading-tab-characters-each-one-with-a-single-space).