# Regex to replace all leading tab characters, each one with a single space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex to replace all leading tab characters with a single space (one space for each leading tab character.

```
// input text with two leading tab characters and two tab characters elsewhere in the text
var input="     Some text       containing tabs";

// A:
console.log(input.replace(/\t/g, "LEADING_TAB_"));  
// prints: "LEADING_TAB_LEADING_TAB_Some textLEADING_TAB_LEADING_TAB_containing tabs"

// B:
console.log(input.replace(/\t/, "LEADING_TAB_"));  
// prints: "LEADING_TAB_   Some text       containing tabs"

// C:
console.log(input.replace(/^(\t)*/, "LEADING_TAB_"));  
// prints: "LEADING_TAB_Some text      containing tabs"

// D:
console.log(input.replace(/\t/gy, "LEADING_TAB_"));  
// prints: "LEADING_TAB_LEADING_TAB_Some text      containing tabs"

// E:
console.log(input.replace(/\t/y, "LEADING_TAB_"));  
// prints: "LEADING_TAB_   Some text       containing tabs"
```

See this in a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/onebcvu4/2/

Answer D work for me.

```
input.replace(/\t/gy, " ")
```

But I don't really understand why. Especially because, according to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky), the global (G) flag should be ignored when used with a sticky flag.

> A regular expression defined as both sticky and global ignores the global flag.

Can anyone claryfy or provide another solution that works?

Comment: I'm going to have to remember that `gy` trick. Nice....

Comment: Wow was really happy to find this. Occasionally, the poking around of closed questions, can have a big payout, this was certainly one of those times. I didn't even know that the y flag existed until reading this Q&A, and yet, it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Answer D works (and is quite clever) because `g` and `y` *aren't* exclusive, but it was reasonable to think they would be. Full details are in the specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexp.prototype-@@replace) and [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexpbuiltinexec), but fundamentally the `g` makes `replace` repeat as long as there is a match, and `y` means that A) the expression only matches at `lastIndex` (which defaults to 0), and B) `lastIndex` is not updated. So you repeatedly match a `\t` at `lastIndex` and replace it until you run out of `\t` at `lastIndex`. Very clever.

If you don't want to use that one, you can also do it with an alternation and a positive look behind:

```
const result = input.replace(/(?:^\t|(?<=^\t*)\t)/g, " ");
```

Live Example:

```js
const input = "\t\tSome text\t\tcontaining tabs";
const result = input.replace(/(?:^\t|(?<=^\t*)\t)/g, " ");

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Or if you're okay with passing a callback to `replace`, it's simpler and doesn't need lookbehind (which is relatively new, ES2018): Match all leading `\t` characters and replace with a string of spaces the same length:

```
const result = input.replace(/^(\t+)/, match => " ".repeat(match.length));
```

Live Example:

```js
const input = "\t\tSome text\t\tcontaining tabs";
const result = input.replace(/^(\t+)/, match => " ".repeat(match.length));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: It's like a post it, it was discovered by accident :) Thanks for clarifying this for me. You've helped me with a PR I was doing for Typescript. (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41269) I hope that's ok for you?